# How can I fetch Jira ticket data with Excel's Power Query functions?

Tags: excel, jira, powerquery

I want to create a fetch query to get data from a saved search of filtered tickets on Jira and get back a table with all the tickets.

I found this URL which does download a CSV file with my goal data. I copied the link when using the "export" function on Jira's search tickets page.

```
https://*****/jira/sr/jira.issuesview.search-request***.csv?delimiter=,
```

But when I enter this URL into Excel Power Query's "Get Data from Web" it returns an unusable HTML in table format and not a CSV with rows for each ticket.

How can I download data via Power Queries from Jira?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can download CSV files from the web, similar to below

```
let Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.csv"),[Delimiter=",",Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Bank Name ", type text}, {"City ", type text}, {"State ", type text}, {"Cert ", Int64.Type}, {"Acquiring Institution ", type text}, {"Closing Date ", type date}, {"Fund", Int64.Type}})
in #"Changed Type"
```

the question I guess is what Jira is putting out

Comment: Using your suggested query with my best guess for a valid Jira tickets data as CSV URL doesn't result in a table with all the all the required tickets. I'm guessing the problem lies with how to get a URL that works for me.

Comment: Find what the proper Jira API is for your use, and use that. Consult https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/ for example how to use API calls in powerquery once you figure out the appropriate Jira syntax   Sounds like the CSV is generated when you ask for it, not necessarily when called by Powequery, hence need for the API

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Connecting-Jira-to-Power-BI-using-the-Web-API/td-p/838130